# Robust match of user input in a while loop

Tags: r

```
while(not_match){
    if(r==1){
      print("Name Player 1: ")
      name1=scan(,what="character",1)
}
}
```

Hi everyone, I want that when the user enters an "enter" when the code asks for the name of Player 1, the code says something like: "This name is invalid", and repeat asking the name of Player 1. I know that I have to use something like: if(length(name1==0))...But I don´t know-how make the code repeat asking the name1. Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This approach should work for you

```
name = readline("Player name: >")
while (!stringr::str_detect("[a-z]", tolower(name)) | name == ""){
  name = readline("Player name: >")
}
```

---

This might be overkill but if you know the names of the players beforehand you can use the `choices` package. Right now, only available on GitHub and install via

```
devtools::install_github("matiasandina/choices")
```

```
library(choices)
players <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Chris")
numeric_menu(players, "Select Player")
```

You will see the menu and you can choose using numbers.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Please see your options below:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Option 1) Alice
Option 2) Bob
Option 3) Chris

Select Player :>
```

The internal function will take care of matching the numbers to the stored player options. Moreover it is robust to "Enter" presses or cats slamming the keyboard

```
Name Player :> sdkjaksdjaksd
Your input is not valid, please enter a number.
Name Player :> kasdjlaksjdlkasasdma
Your input is not valid, please enter a number.
Name Player :> 
Your input is not valid, please enter a number.
Name Player :> ?
Your input is not valid, please enter a number.
Name Player :> 54
Option is not valid. Choose again
Name Player :>
```

> Disclaimer: I am the author of choices package, more info [here](https://github.com/matiasandina/choices)

Comment: Thank you but I can´t use externals packages.

Comment: well...if you only want to check for "Enter" you can change your condition to only `name == ""` and no packages involved